# Querying an embedded list in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a document in my OrientDB database (version 1.0.1), with a structure largely like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "...",
    "duration": 665,
    "testcases": [
        {
            "testName": "test01",
            "type": "ignore",
            "filename": "tests/test1.js"
        },
        {
            "iterations": 1,
            "runningTime": 45,
            "testName": "test02",
            "type": "pass",
            "filename": "tests/test1.js"
        },
        ...
        {
            "testName": "test05",
            "type": "ignore",
            "filename": "tests/test1.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I query across the entire list, eg. if I want to find all documents that contain a testcase with the type "ignore"?

I've attempted the following query

```
select from testresult where testcases['type'] = 'ignore'
```

but this results in a `NumberFormatException`.

```
select from testresult where testcases[0]['type'] = 'ignore'
```

works, but obviously only looks at the first list element of each document.

```
select from testresult where testcases contains(type = 'ignore')
```

Doesn't provide any results, but the query is accepted as valid.

**Update:** 
The following query works as intended, if the testcases are stored as separate documents instead of as an embedded list.

```
select from testresult where testcases contains (type = 'ignore')
```

Comment: I had the same issue you did. You could post your update in the question and accept it. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: @DavidLaberge : Thanks for the suggestion. The question is so old that I frankly don't completely remember its context, so I would feel a bit uneasy about that manoeuvre. I also have a feeling that my initial approach ought to work, at least according to the documentation of OrientDB, so it would feel wrong to encourage people to restructure their databases like in the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it's an old question but I had the same problem and just stubled upon an answer here:
https://www.mail-archive.com/orient-database@googlegroups.com/msg00662.html

The following should work. It does in my very similiar use case.

```
select from testresult where 'ignore' in testcases.type
```

Comment: The usual sql statement `where testcases.type in 'ignore'` didn't work with orientdb. Orientdb goes with proper english :)

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem and end up with :

```
select * from testresult 
  let $tmp = (select from 
    (select expand(testcases) from testresult ) 
  where 
    value.type = 'ignore') 
where 
  testcases in $tmp.value
```

this will give you all the testresult documents that contains at least one testcase which type is ignore. This query works on embedded lists. Take care that expand function is available in OrientDB >= 1.4.0.

The inner query :

```
select from (select expand(testcases) from testresult) where value.type='ignore'
```

select only the different testcases with a type = 'ignore'. The result are testcases. To have the whole document we match those testcases with the ones contained in each document (testcases in $tmp.value).

I don't know if there is a simpler way to query embedded list...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select from testresult where testcases traverse ( type = 'ignore' )
```

Check the traverse operator ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/orient-database/zoBGmIg85o4 ) to know how to use the fetchplan or put any() instead of testcases just after "where".

For example we have a class called Country which has an embeddedlist property with some of its isoCodes. If we attempt the following query :

```
select name,description,isoCodes,status from Country where isoCodes traverse ( value = 'GB' OR value = 'IT' )
```

Orientdb Rest interface provides :

```
{
  "result": [{
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
"name": "Italy", 
  "isoCodes": [
    {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
    "code": "iso3166-A2", 
    "value": "IT"
      }, 
    {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
    "code": "iso3166-A3", 
    "value": "ITA"
      }], 
  "status": [
    {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
    "status": "1", 
    "startingDate": "2012-04-24"
      }]
    }, {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
"name": "United Kingdom", 
  "isoCodes": [
    {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
    "code": "iso3166-A2", 
    "value": "GB"
      }, 
    {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
    "code": "iso3166-A3", 
    "value": "GBR"
      }], 
  "status": [
    {
      "@type": "d", "@version": 0, 
    "status": "1", 
    "startingDate": "2012-04-24"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps!!.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It unfortunately did not improve my situation. The suggested query works perfectly as long as the embedded list contains links to other documents, but provides no results when the objects in the list are just values, ie. the same situation I had reached when I updated my question. Are you dead-certain that your IsoCodes properties are not separate documents in your database?